# Is there a way to find out which app posted a tweet?

Tags: rest, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm using the Twitter OAuth API and would like find out who is using my app.
Is there an option to check through Twitters REST API which app/client posted a tweet?

Answer (score 0):

No.  But you can make your app record the user's name and then send it back to you.  Assuming you have permission to do that.